# timer.schedule() in not working at all (in Java)

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer, awt

I made a simple program in Java which draws a rectangle on a canvas. And then the rectangle starts moving along X-axis, from left to right.
But the timer.schedule() function is not working. Following is the code:-

```
package firstanimation;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Timer;


public class FirstAnimation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Frame frame = new Frame("SomeRandomName");

        frame.setBounds(50, 50, 700, 500);
        frame.setBackground(Color.red);

        MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();

        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Graphics graph = frame.getGraphics();

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        Task task = new Task(canvas, graph);

        timer.schedule(task, 1000,1000);

    }
}



package firstanimation;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyCanvas extends Canvas{

    public int x,y,width,height;

    public MyCanvas()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        width = 50;
        height = 50;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        x+=10;
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }



}



package firstanimation;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Task extends TimerTask{

    private MyCanvas canvas;
    private Graphics graphics;

    public Task(MyCanvas can, Graphics g)
    {
        super();
        canvas = can;
        graphics = g;
        canvas.paint(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        canvas.update(graphics);
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

But the strange thing is... Every time i'm maximizing and restoring the frame, the box is moving.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "But the strange thing is... Every time i'm maximizing and restoring the frame, the box is moving. Why is this happening?"

Because `repaint()` is called when you resize which update the graphics, which *you* should be doing, instead of trying to call `paint`.

## **But...**

Still many things wrong.

Seeing as this is your first animation (package firstanimation;), let me get you started in the *right* direction.

1. Don't use Canvas. Use `JPanel` or `JComponent` instead. When you do, don't override `paint` but `paintComponent` instead. Also make sure you call `super.paintComponent` so you aren't let with any paint artifact during the animation.

   ```
   public class MyCanvas extends JPanel {
       @Override
       protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           super.paintComponent(g);

           //painting code
       }
   }
   ```
2. Never use `getGraphics` on a component to do any painting.
3. You shouldn't ever have to explicitly call `paint`. The `paint[Component]` method will be implicitly called for you. A simple call to `repaint()` will repaint the component.
4. I just realized you're using all AWT components. Don't use them, they're out-dated. Instead use Swing component. The majority of them are just prefixed with a `J`, like `Frame` -> `JFrame`. They are in the `javax.swing.*` package.
5. For animation use a `javax.swing.Timer`. You can see more at [How to Use Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). The basic construct is

   ```
   Timer ( int delayInMillis, ActionListener listener )
   ```

   where `delayInMillis` is the time to delay between ticks(in this case animations) and the `ActionListener` listens for "ticks". Each tick, the `actionPerformed` of the `ActionListener` is called. There, you can put the code to update any variables you use for animation.

---

I suggest you read the tutorials [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to see the proper way to paint.

Here's a simple example with all the points above mentioned

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class AnimateBall extends JPanel {

    private static final int D_W = 500;
    private static final int D_H = 300;

    private Ball ball;

    public AnimateBall() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randX = rand.nextInt(D_W);
        int randY = rand.nextInt(D_H);
        ball = new Ball(randX, randY);

        Timer timer = new Timer(15, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ball.animate();

                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
            ball.drawBall(g);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);
    }

    public class Ball {

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0; // Current ball position
        int dx = 4; // Increment on ball's x-coordinate
        int dy = 4; // Increment on ball's y-coordinate
        int radius = 15; // Ball radius

        public Ball(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        Color color = new Color((int) (Math.random() * 256),
                (int) (Math.random() * 256), (int) (Math.random() * 256));

        public void drawBall(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
        }

        public void animate() {
            if (x < 0 || x > getWidth()) {
                dx = -dx;
            }
            if (y < 0 || y > getHeight()) {
                dy = -dy;
            }
            // Adjust ball position
            x += dx;
            y += dy;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new AnimateBall());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to add one more thing to make it worth. I called update() instead of repaint(). It was troubling me.